# How to append the value to the url in symfony2

Tags: symfony, symfony-2.1

I have a users list page where admin can delete a user.i have a controller when user click on delete button the respective id is passed through the url and my url looks deleteuser?id=2
like this.Now the problem is i need a confirmation for the admin whether he can click yes to delete user,and no to cancel

```
<a href="<?php echo $view['router']->generate('deleteuser',array('id'=>$id,)))?>">
<input type="submit" name="Yes" class="btn btn-success" value=Yes /></a>  
<a href="<?php echo $view['router']->generate('deleteuser',array('id'=>$id,))?>"><input type="submit" name="No" class="btn" data-dismiss="modal" value="No"/></a>
```

Now i need to pass the controller whether the admin clicked the yes or no value with the url
i.e i need to append the selected value to the url and get in the controller

Comment: why don't you call controller only if "yes" is clicked?

Comment: The problem is iam calling the controller in both yes and no cases,if the value is yes i called a function to repository which will delete particular user and displayes user's list and if the value is no it will display the only users list.here iam using confirmation box i.e yes or no is boostrap model thanks for your reply